# Azure Data Factory File Name Option Pattern value picked from select activity output

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have multiple source .csv files in the Azure BLOB storage where each file has the same name as its "label" column value. We loop through each of these files via the ForEach loop which contains a single DataFlow:

[image]

The problem is that we were only able to use the "Default" value for the "File name option" field which sets the auto-generated GUID for the file name. We would like to use the "label" field's value within the "Pattern" field and change it a bit.

The "SelectColumns" step outputs the following mapping:
[image]

Question: **Is it possible to pass the "label" column's value to the "Pattern" field and modify it?**
For example, if the label's value is `has_stuff` the sink activity would output `has_stuff_log`.

If it's not possible, how would I pass the ForEach `item().name` to that field?

Comment: Your sink file names should be pattern1.csv, pattern2.csv right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The sink file should be `has_stuff_log`, `has_other_log` etc. Where the naming starts with the label value and ends with "_log".

Comment: So, you want to split you data as per the data and write it to seperate files. right?

Comment: Yes, there is a Conditional Split activity before the "SelectColumns" activity. I'm filtering out the invalid rows and moving them into a separate file that ends with postfix "_log". Also should note that in each file all the "label" values are the same. So, It's okay to just get the first-row value for that "label" column. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all of your values in the column `label` are same, add the `'_log.csv'` using derived column after the select transformation and use this column in the sink file name settings.

```
concat(label, '_log.csv')
```

[image]

**Derived column results:**

[image]

Now, use this column in the sink file name settings like below.

[image]

**Result file after pipeline execution:**

[image]

Comment: Looks great, will test it out and mark it as an answer afterward, thanks!